# How to identify if a row exists for 2 separate entities

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. I have a query which I am not able to get the result of.

From the below table, I need to list down Astronauts (astrno) who flew both 'Apollo' and 'Shuttle' mission (projectname).

```
projectname  | missionno | astrono |  role
--------------+-----------+---------+----------------------
 Apollo       | 1         |      22 | Commander
 Apollo       | 1         |      42 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 1         |      10 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 7         |      33 | Commander
 Apollo       | 7         |      16 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 7         |      14 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 8         |       5 | Commander
 Apollo       | 8         |      27 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 8         |       2 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 9         |      29 | Commander
 Apollo       | 9         |      36 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 9         |      35 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 10        |      39 | Commander
 Apollo       | 10        |      44 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 10        |       9 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 11        |       3 | Commander
 Apollo       | 11        |      11 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 11        |       1 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 12        |      12 | Commander
 Apollo       | 12        |      21 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 12        |       4 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 13        |      27 | Commander
 Apollo       | 13        |      40 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 13        |      23 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 14        |      37 | Commander
 Apollo       | 14        |      32 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 14        |      30 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 15        |      43 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 15        |      24 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 16        |      44 | Commander
 Apollo       | 16        |      28 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 16        |      15 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 17        |       9 | Commander
 Apollo       | 17        |      17 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo       | 17        |      34 | Lunar Module Pilot
 Skylab       | 2         |      12 | Commander
 Skylab       | 2         |      41 | Pilot
 Skylab       | 2         |      25 | Scientist
 Skylab       | 3         |       4 | Commander
 Skylab       | 3         |      26 | Pilot
 Skylab       | 3         |      18 | Scientist
 Skylab       | 4         |       8 | Commander
 Skylab       | 4         |      31 | Pilot
 Skylab       | 4         |      19 | Scientist
 Apollo-Soyuz | 1         |      39 | Commander
 Apollo-Soyuz | 1         |       6 | Command Module Pilot
 Apollo-Soyuz | 1         |      38 | Docking Module Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-1     |      44 | Commander
 Shuttle      | STS-1     |     119 | Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-2     |     138 | Commander
 Shuttle      | STS-2     |     408 | Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-3     |      25 | Commander
 Shuttle      | STS-3     |     156 | Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-4     |      28 | Commander
 Shuttle      | STS-4     |     191 | Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-5     |       6 | Commander
 Shuttle      | STS-5     |     309 | Pilot
 Shuttle      | STS-5     |      53 | Mission Specialist
 Shuttle      | STS-5     |     245 | Mission Specialist
```

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use conditional aggregation over the records for each astronaut:

```
SELECT astrono
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY astrono
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN projectname = 'Apollo'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN projectname = 'Shuttle' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the exists condition

Select astrono from table t where exists (select 1 from table where astrono=t.astrono and project name='Apollo')and exists (select 1 from table where astrono=t.astrono and projectname ='Shuttle');

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step-by-step. We the following query, we take all rows from the original table that have to do with the `Apollo` and `Shuttle` projects only.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE projectname IN ('Apollo', 'Shuttle')
```

Then, since we don't care about the specific projects, let's modify the above query to return the project projects for each astronaut:

```
SELECT astrono, count(*) AS count
FROM mytable
WHERE projectname IN ('Apollo', 'Shuttle')
GROUP BY astrono
```

Finally, we can keep only the astronauts that participated in at least two projects based on the above count:

```
SELECT astrono
FROM mytable
WHERE projectname IN ('Apollo', 'Shuttle')
GROUP BY astrono
HAVING count(*)>=2;
```

Since we have eliminated all rows referring to other projects, and if we assume that a combination of astronaut and project can appear at most once, then if an astronaut is found to have participated in two projects based on the above count, those two projects have to be `Apollo` and `Shuttle`.

If you don't like the assumption above that each combination of astronaut and project can appear at most once, you could alternatively do it as follows:

```
SELECT astrono
FROM mytable
GROUP BY astrono
HAVING bool_or(projectname='Apollo') OR bool_or(projectname='Shuttle');
```

Comment: This query won't work if there are duplicates possible.  For this reason, conditional aggregation is safer.